# twai/can RX messages receiving is not working is not working in the ESP32-S2 code

Tags: esp32, can-bus, arduino-esp32

SO, I have been trying to test the CAN Bus communication protocol known as "twai" in the esp32-s2 chip.

I have the chip - Arduino wires - can transceiver (SN65HVD230).
Rx is connected to port4
Tx is connected to port5

the receiving of messages is not working and idk why
the following output shows.

```
Failed to receive message
Message queued for transmission
Failed to receive message
Message queued for transmission
Failed to receive message
Message queued for transmission
Failed to receive message
Message queued for transmission
Failed to receive message
Message queued for transmission
Failed to receive message
Failed to queue message for transmission
Failed to receive message
Failed to queue message for transmission
Failed to receive message
Failed to queue message for transmission
Failed to receive message
Failed to queue message for transmission
Failed to receive message
Failed to queue message for transmission
Failed to receive message
Failed to queue message for transmission
Failed to receive message
Failed to queue message for transmission
Failed to receive message
Failed to queue message for transmission
Failed to receive message
Failed to queue message for transmission
Failed to receive message
Failed to queue message for transmission
Failed to receive message
Failed to queue message for transmission
Failed to receive message
Failed to queue message for transmission
Failed to receive message
Failed to queue message for transmission
Failed to receive message
Failed to queue message for transmission
```

this is the code i used, idk what is wrong in it, i got the commands from the espressif link

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/twai.html

it should be similar to the CAN interface in the regular esp32 chip.

this is the code used

```
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "driver/twai.h"

void setup()

{
  Serial.begin(115200);

    //    Initialize configuration structures using macro initializers

    twai_general_config_t g_config = TWAI_GENERAL_CONFIG_DEFAULT(GPIO_NUM_5, GPIO_NUM_4, TWAI_MODE_NORMAL);
    twai_timing_config_t t_config = TWAI_TIMING_CONFIG_250KBITS();
    twai_filter_config_t f_config = TWAI_FILTER_CONFIG_ACCEPT_ALL();



    //    Install TWAI driver
    if (twai_driver_install(&g_config, &t_config, &f_config) == ESP_OK)
    {
        printf("Driver installed\n");
    } else {
        printf("Failed to install driver\n");
        return;
    }



    //    Start TWAI driver
    if (twai_start() == ESP_OK) {
        printf("Driver started\n");
    } else {
        printf("Failed to start driver\n");
        return;
    }
}


void loop() {

//Configure message to transmit
twai_message_t message;
message.identifier =0x12;
message.extd =1;              

message.data_length_code = 8;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    message.data[i] = 0;
}



//Queue message for transmission
if (twai_transmit(&message, pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000)) == ESP_OK) {
    printf("Message queued for transmission\n");
} else {
    printf("Failed to queue message for transmission\n");
}

delay(2000);

twai_message_t messagerx;
if (twai_receive(&messagerx, pdMS_TO_TICKS(10000)) == ESP_OK) {
    printf("Message received\n");
} else {
    printf("Failed to receive message\n");
    return;
}


//Process received message
if (messagerx.extd) {
    printf("Message is in Extended Format\n");
} else {
    printf("Message is in Standard Format\n");
}
printf("ID is %d\n", messagerx.identifier);
if (!(messagerx.rtr)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < messagerx.data_length_code; i++) {
        printf("Data byte %d = %d\n", i, message.data[i]);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a known issue with the ESP32-S2 devices where TWAI receive does not function properly, while transmit will function correctly. It effects v4.3 of the ESP-IDF TWAI driver as of writing this answer.

EspressIF will be back porting the fix to v4.3 according to this Github issue; https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/5604 , however does not yet appear to be complete as the pull request is still marked WIP.

I was able to confirm using similar code to yours by switching back to an ESP32 module and receive would then work correctly.